# Does the incompatible notions of theology in islam and christianity resolve the differences or aggravate them. How can one judge right or wrong?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, christianity, belief, comparative-religions, divine-attributes

### I had certain questions related to islam and I hope this site gonna address them positively.

To start with I was going through a question asked at Christianity Stackexchange site relate to nature of God:
**In what way(s) is God the Father a father to God the Son? And in what way(s) is God the Son a son?**

**There were various answers. I'll provide with one of them and only few lines for brevity:**

The human 'senses' are not capable of either perceiving or understanding that which is eternal ; that which is of Spirit ; or that which is Divine.

None of the human 'senses' (which are created, not begotten of Spirit) are able to communicate with the invisible, the unhearable, the untouchable, and the unthinkable.

> But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned. [1 Corinthians 2:14 KJV]

In other words : the things of God, who is Spirit, make no sense to the natural man. Or, according to the edited question : the way in which they operate is meaningless to the natural man.

This is why the natural heart and mind of man can neither appreciate, nor enter into, the knowledge of Deity ; and, most particularly, the relationship of (as you, yourself, precisely state) 'God, the Father' and 'God, the Son : words which the human mind cannot possibly process, there being 'One God'.

You can read further here:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96217/in-what-ways-is-god-the-father-a-father-to-god-the-son-and-in-what-ways-is

And another one at the same site: **How is the Son begotten?**

One of the answer was as follows:

**Corporeal begetting ( Human)**

```
-Maturation age ( fertile couple at least at the onset of puberty)

-Female wife is needed

-Sex is needed

-Offspring has beginning of existence
```

**Spiritual begetting ( divine)**

```
-At the first instance of existence, God begets, that is, because God is eternal he begets eternally ( John 5:26)

-Begetting doesn’t involve a female wife ( John 4:24, Psalm 45:1LXX)

-Begetting doesn’t involve sex ( John 4:24, Psalm 110:3 LXX)

-Son has no beginning of existence ( John 1:1, 1 John 1:1-3)
```

For further reading:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20647/how-is-the-son-begotten

**Also I went through a site. The person is my countryfellow. He wrote:**

It is absolutely not possible for God to beget a son as a man begets a son. This could never be. God is incapable of such a physical act and we must never think of God in this way. Christians do not believe that Jesus is the Son of God in the physical concept of its meaning but absolutely in a spiritual sense.

The Qur’an raises the following objection:

> Surah 6:101: “How could He have a son when He has no wife?” (A. Bewley)

Observe carefully how Islam attributes the carnal and physical traits of humans to God in this Qur’anic verse. No consideration whatsoever is given for the divinely infinite nature of the holiness of God. Just because men on earth cannot have sons unless they cohabit with their wives, so the Qur’an blasphemously concludes that God, too, cannot have a son unless he cohabits with a woman. Muhammad could not see beyond the carnal. He could not see beyond the temporal to understand the divine nature of God. Muhammad could not see the utter debased profanity of Allah in this Qur’anic verse.

https://aslamsheriqbal.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/surah-1919-jesus-christ-in-the-quran/

A christian site https://www.gotquestions.org/eternal-generation.html defines their core beliefs as follows:

> The doctrine of eternal generation essentially teaches that God the Father eternally and by necessity generates or begets God the Son in such a way that the substance (divine essence) of God is not divided. The Person of God the Son derives His deity from this generation. In other words, there is a communication of the whole, indivisible substance of the Godhead so that God the Son is the exact representation (or express image) of God the Father. There is still one divine essence that eternally exists in two persons through eternal generation. Reformed theologian Louis Berkhof states the doctrine of eternal generation in this way:

> It is that eternal and necessary act of the first person in the Trinity, whereby He, within the divine Being, is the ground of a second personal subsistence like His own, and puts this second person in possession of the whole divine essence, without any division, alienation, or change (Systematic Theology, pg. 94).

Early church fathers wrote a lot about explaining this: For example **Theophilus of Antioch** said:

> “Not as the poets and writers of myths talk of the sons of gods begotten from intercourse [with women], but as truth expounds, the Word, that always exists, residing within the heart of God. For before anything came into being He had Him as a counsellor, being His own mind and thought. But when God wished to make all that He determined on, He begot this Word, uttered,61 the first-born of all creation, not Himself being emptied of the Word [Reason], but having begotten Reason, and always conversing with His Reason. And hence the holy writings teach us, and all the spirit-bearing [inspired] men, one of whom, John, says, “In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God,” (Joh_1:1) showing that at first God was alone, and the Word in Him. Then he says, “The Word was God; all things came into existence through Him; and apart from Him not one thing came into existence.” The Word, then, being God, and being naturally62 produced from God, whenever the Father of the universe wills, He sends Him to any place; and He, coming, is both heard and seen, being sent by Him, and is found in a place.”

**Tertullian** wrote:

> ” Chap. XIX. – Christ, as to His Divine Nature, as the Word of God, Became Flesh, Not by Carnal Conception, nor by the Will of the Flesh and of Man, but by the Will of God. Christ’s Divine Nature, of Its Own Accord, Descended into the Virgin’s Womb.”

For further reading: https://answeringislamblog.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/church-fathers-on-eternal-generation/

**I'll summarize whole discussion as follows:**

- Don't these huge discrepancies between the two mainstream religions of world push them further apart rather than bringing them closer?
- Christianity perceive and interpret their theological ideas based on philosophical or metaphycial grounds whereas all of the quran refutations are based on corporeal grounds like the verse discussed above and quran 19:89-92)?
- Muslim evangelists are still conceiving their doctrinal terms wrong like begotten son leading to commoners to misconceptions about what they believe
- Muslim evangelists and apologetics not addressing their core beliefs accurately.  Rebutting rather than inviting them through rationale.
- Having said all of this, how can one judge which course is right or wrong. Well I'm not gonna argue that bible is not distorted. But how all the islamic resources including quran, classical commentaries and islamic sites construe whatever let's say forgery is written according to their own understandings, it's obviously gonna seems absurd and dubious?
- What should be the attitude of laymen not enough well versed in comparative theological studies. Should these matters be left as how they are without indulging in these depths?

I hope someone can deal with and clarify my doubts and misunderstandings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Early scholars in Islam, including commentators and theologians, approached theological concepts with deep knowledge and understanding of the Quran, the Hadiths, and the Arabic language. They dedicated their lives to studying and interpreting these sources to gain insights into the teachings of Islam.

When it comes to concepts like Christology, it is important to note that Islam has its own distinct understanding of Jesus (peace be upon him) and his role as a prophet. Islamic scholars approached these concepts based on the teachings of the Quran and the Hadiths, which provide a different perspective from Christian theology.

Early Islamic scholars engaged in rigorous intellectual debates and discussions to address theological questions and challenges. They used various methodologies, including linguistic analysis, contextual understanding, and comparative studies, to interpret and explain the teachings of Islam.

It is true that there are differences in the understanding of certain theological concepts between Islam and Christianity. These differences arise from the divergent theological frameworks and perspectives of the two religions. However, it is important to approach these discussions with respect and a willingness to understand each other's beliefs.

It is worth noting that Islamic scholars, like any other scholars, may have had different interpretations and viewpoints on certain matters. This diversity of opinions is a natural part of scholarly discourse and does not diminish the overall contributions of early Islamic scholars to the development of Islamic theology.

In summary, early Islamic scholars approached theological concepts by relying on the Quran, the Hadiths, and their deep knowledge of the Arabic language. They engaged in intellectual debates and discussions, using various methodologies to interpret and explain the teachings of Islam. While differences exist between Islamic and Christian theology, it is important to approach these discussions with respect and a willingness to understand each other's perspectives.

Answer (score -2):

As Muslims, we believe in the importance of respecting and understanding the beliefs of others. It is true that there are differences between Islamic and Christian doctrines, as each religion has its own unique teachings and perspectives. However, it is not accurate to say that Muslims do not perceive Christian doctrines precisely.

Muslim scholars have studied and engaged with Christian beliefs throughout history, and there are numerous Islamic texts and resources that discuss and critique Christian doctrines. It is important to note that Islamic scholars approach the study of other religions with respect and academic rigor, seeking to understand their beliefs accurately.

However, it is also important to recognize that individuals may have varying levels of knowledge and understanding about other religions, including Christianity. It is not appropriate to generalize the views of all Muslims based on the knowledge or understanding of a few individuals.

If you have specific questions about Islamic teachings or would like to discuss any specific Christian doctrines, I am here to provide information based on Islamic sources.

Comment: Christians say that Islamic resources like early commentators or predecessors don't quite understand Christology and related concepts leading them to misconstrue the doctrines like taking the terms used in philosophical or theological senses like "begotten" in carnal senses accusing opposing group in believing allegedly false doctrines. Well whatever may be the case how earlier scholars approached their problems? I often wonder if it truely is the case that Quran is offended by these filial terms like son and begotten due to association with zoological conception of the terms?

Comment: This leads me thinking that early classical commentators have had wrong interpretations of their beliefs and even today Muslim daee's arguing that these terms dealing with functions of lower class species can't be attributed to God being unfamiliar of their doctrines and  imposing their own interpretations ain't gonna convince them afterall. What should be the stance of a layman not having a firm background in comparative theology towards these conflicting ideas existing within each religion which are not in coherence and dawah seems purposeless.